# Tex Studio bib file error

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

When I compile my .bib file in texstudio it says that log file is not [image]

[image]

However when I compile the latexcode which refers to that .bib file. I can see the reference page, However let say I cite a journal, I can see the authors, name of the journal, and published date but I cant see the journal name.

Apart from that the capitalization in the paper name is missing

How I can rectify this issue?

Comment: You have to run `bibtex` on your `.bib` file. See the `tools` menu.

Comment: @Sigur Yeah. I did like that, but the problem is still there.

Comment: To prevent the name "Steiner" from being typeset in all-lowercase, encase it in curly braces. I.e., set the `author` field as follows: `{On the problem of {Steiner}},`. You should probably also insert a comma between the author's surname and the initials of his/her first and middle names, i.e., have `author = {Melzak, Z.A.},`. Finally, although not strictly required for entries of type `@article`, you may want to do your readers a service by providing information for the `volume`, `issue`, and `pages` fields.

Answer (score 2):

`journaltitle` is the name of the field used by `biblatex`. It seems that you are using `bibtex` (without `biblatex`) and that field is not recognised by `bibtex`. The name of the field in bibtex is `journal`.